# Natural merge sort in Java - follow-up

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, mergesort

See the previous iteration: [Natural merge sort in Java](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/71235/natural-merge-sort-in-java)

See the next iteration: [Natural merge sort in Java - follow-up 2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/106240/natural-merge-sort-in-java-follow-up-2)

**Arrays.java**

```
package net.coderodde.util;

/**
 * This class contains static methods implementing a natural merge sort
 * algorithm, which runs in time <tt>O(n log m)</tt>, where <tt>n</tt> is the
 * length of the range to sort and <tt>m</tt> is the amount of ascending or 
 * strictly descending contiguous subsequences usually called 'runs' in the
 * input range. The algorithm is stable.
 * 
 * @author Rodion Efremov
 * @version 2014.12.01
 */
public class Arrays {

    /**
     * Sorts the entire input array. 
     */
    public static final <E extends Comparable<? super E>>
        void sort(final E[] array) {
        sort(array, 0, array.length);       
    }

    /**
     * Sorts a specific range in the input array.
     */
    public static final <E extends Comparable<? super E>> 
        void sort(final E[] array, final int fromIndex, final int toIndex) {
        if (toIndex - fromIndex < 2) {
            // Trivially sorted or indices are ass-backwards.
            return;
        }

        final UnsafeIntQueue queue = buildRunSizeQueue(array, 
                                                       fromIndex, 
                                                       toIndex);

        final E[] buffer = array.clone();
        final int mergePasses = getPassAmount(queue.size());

        E[] source;
        E[] target;

        if ((mergePasses & 1) == 1) {
            // Odd amount of passes over the entire range, set the buffer array 
            // as source so that the sorted shit ends up in the original array.
            source = buffer;
            target = array;
        } else {
            source = array;
            target = buffer;
        }

        // The amount of runs in current merge pass that were not processed yet.
        int runsLeft = queue.size();
        int offset = fromIndex;

        // While there are runs to merge, do:
        while (queue.size() > 1) {
            final int leftRunLength =  queue.dequeue();
            final int rightRunLength = queue.dequeue();

            merge(source, 
                  target, 
                  offset, 
                  leftRunLength, 
                  rightRunLength);

            // Bounce the run we obtained by merging the two runs to the tail.
            queue.enqueue(leftRunLength + rightRunLength);

            runsLeft -= 2;
            offset += leftRunLength + rightRunLength;

            switch (runsLeft) {
                case 1:
                    final int singleLength = queue.dequeue();
                    // In the target array, this 'unmarried' run might be
                    // in the form of two unmerged runs.
                    System.arraycopy(source, 
                                     offset, 
                                     target, 
                                     offset, 
                                     singleLength);
                    queue.enqueue(singleLength);

                    // FALL THROUGH!

                case 0:
                    runsLeft = queue.size();
                    offset = fromIndex;
                    final E[] tmp = source;
                    source = target;
                    target = tmp;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reverses the range <code>array[fromIndex ... toIndex - 1]</code>. Used 
     * for making descending runs ascending.
     * 
     * @param <E> the component type.
     * @param array the array holding the desired range.
     * @param fromIndex the least index of the range to reverse.
     * @param toIndex the index one past the greatest index of the range.
     */
    public static <E> void reverseRun(final E[] array, 
                                      final int fromIndex,
                                      final int toIndex) {
        for(int l = fromIndex, r = toIndex - 1; l < r; ++l, --r) {
            final E tmp = array[l];
            array[l] = array[r];
            array[r] = tmp;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Checks whether all given arrays are of the same length and has identical
     * references at every corresponding array components.
     */
    public static final <E> boolean arraysEqual(final E[]... arrays) {
        if (arrays.length < 2) {
            return true;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < arrays.length - 1; ++i) {
            if (arrays[i].length != arrays[i + 1].length) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        for (int idx = 0; idx < arrays[0].length; ++idx) {
            for (int i = 0; i < arrays.length - 1; ++i) {
                if (arrays[i][idx] != arrays[i + 1][idx]) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * This static class method implements the actual merging routine.
     * 
     * @param <E> the array component type.
     * @param source the source array.
     * @param target the target array.
     * @param offset amount of elements to skip from the beginning of each
     * array.
     * @param leftRunLength the length of the left run.
     * @param rightRunLength the length of the right run.
     */
    private static <E extends Comparable<? super E>> 
        void merge(final E[] source, 
                   final E[] target, 
                   int offset,
                   int leftRunLength,
                   int rightRunLength) {
        int left = offset;
        int right = left + leftRunLength;

        final int leftBound = right;
        final int rightBound = right + rightRunLength;

        while (left < leftBound && right < rightBound) {
            target[offset++] = source[right].compareTo(source[left]) < 0 ? 
                               source[right++] :
                               source[left++];
        }

        // Either 'left < leftBound' or 'right < rightBound', not both.
        if (left < leftBound) {
            System.arraycopy(source, left, target, offset, leftBound - left);
        } else if (right < rightBound) {
            System.arraycopy(source, right, target, offset, rightBound - right);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This class method returns the amount of merge passes over the input range
     * needed to sort <code>runAmount</code> runs.
     */
    private static int getPassAmount(int runAmount) {
        int setBitCount = 0;
        int mostSignificantBitIndex = -1;
        int mask = 0x40000000;

        loop:
        for (int i = 30; i >= 0; --i, mask >>= 1) {
            if ((runAmount & mask) != 0) {
                ++setBitCount;

                switch (setBitCount) {
                    case 1:
                        mostSignificantBitIndex = i;
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        break loop;
                }
            }
        }

        if (setBitCount > 1) {
            // Once here, 'runAmount' is not a power of two; make it one.
            runAmount = (1 << (mostSignificantBitIndex + 1));
        }

        int ret = 0;

        while ((runAmount & 1) == 0) {
            ++ret;
            runAmount >>= 1;
        }

        return ret;
    }

    /**
     * Scans the runs over the range 
     * <code>array[fromIndex .. toIndex - 1]</code> and returns a 
     * {@link UnsafeIntQueue} containing the sizes of scanned runs in the same
     * order as they appear in the input range.
     * 
     * @param <E> the component type.
     * @param array the array containing the desired range.
     * @param fromIndex the least index of the range to process.
     * @param toIndex the index one past the greatest index contained by the
     * range.
     * 
     * @return a {@link UnsafeIntQueue} describing the lengths of the runs in 
     * the input range.
     */
    static <E extends Comparable<? super E>> 
        UnsafeIntQueue buildRunSizeQueue(final E[] array, 
                                         final int fromIndex,
                                         final int toIndex) {
        final UnsafeIntQueue queue = 
          new UnsafeIntQueue(((toIndex - fromIndex) >>> 1) + 1);

        int head;
        int left = fromIndex;
        int right = left + 1;
        final int last = toIndex - 1;

        while (left < last) {
            head = left;

            // Decide the direction of the next run.
            if (array[left++].compareTo(array[right++]) <= 0) {
                // Scan an ascending run.
                while (left < last
                        && array[left].compareTo(array[right]) <= 0) {
                    ++left;
                    ++right;
                }

                queue.enqueue(left - head + 1);
            } else {
                // Scan a strictly descending run.
                while (left < last
                        && array[left].compareTo(array[right]) > 0)  {
                    ++left;
                    ++right;
                }

                queue.enqueue(left - head + 1);
                // We reverse a strictly descending run as to minimize the
                // the amount of runs scanned in total. Strictness is required.
                reverseRun(array, head, right);
            }

            ++left;
            ++right;
        }

        // A special case: the very last element may be left without buddies
        // so make it (the only) 1-element run.
        if (left == last) {
            queue.enqueue(1);
        }

        return queue;
    }

    /**
     * This is the implementation class for an array-based queue of integers. It 
     * sacrifices under- and overflow checks as to squeeze a little bit more of
     * efficiency and thus is an ad-hoc data structure hidden from the client
     * programmers.
     * 
     * @author Rodion Efremov
     * @version 2014.12.01
     */
    private static class UnsafeIntQueue {

        /**
         * The minimum capacity of this queue.
         */
        private static final int MINIMUM_CAPACITY = 256;

        /**
         * Stores the actual elements.
         */
        private final int[] storage;

        /**
         * Points to the element that will be dequeued next.
         */
        private int head;

        /**
         * Points to the array component to which the next element will be 
         * inserted.
         */
        private int tail;

        /**
         * Caches the amount of elements stored.
         */
        private int size;

        /**
         * Used for faster head/tail updates.
         */
        private final int mask;

        /**
         * Creates an empty integer queue with capacity of the least power of
         * two no less than original capacity value.
         */
        UnsafeIntQueue(int capacity) {
            capacity = fixCapacity(capacity);
            this.mask = capacity - 1;
            this.storage = new int[capacity];
        }

        /**
         * Appends a run size to the tail of this queue.
         * 
         * @param runSize the run size to append.
         */
        void enqueue(int runSize) {
            storage[tail & mask] = runSize;
            tail = (tail + 1) & mask;
            ++size;
        }

        /**
         * Pops from the head of this queue a run size.
         * 
         * @return the run size at the head of this queue.
         */
        int dequeue() {
            int ret = storage[head];
            head = (head + 1) & mask;
            --size;
            return ret;
        }

        /**
         * Returns the amount of values stored in this queue.
         */
        int size() {
            return size;
        }

        /**
         * This routine is responsible for computing an integer that is a power
         * of two no less than <code>capacity</code>.
         */
        private static int fixCapacity(int capacity) {
            if (capacity < MINIMUM_CAPACITY) {
                capacity = MINIMUM_CAPACITY;
            }

            int mask = 0x40000000;
            int totalSetBits = 0;
            int mostSignificantBitIndex = -1;

            loop:
            for (int i = 30; i >= 0; mask >>= 1, --i) {
                if ((capacity & mask) != 0) {
                    ++totalSetBits;

                    switch (totalSetBits) {
                        case 1:
                            mostSignificantBitIndex = i;
                            break;

                        case 2:
                            break loop;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (totalSetBits > 1) {
                // Make capacity a power of two that is no less than
                // input capacity
                capacity = (1 << (mostSignificantBitIndex + 1));
            }

            // Here, capacity is a power of two.
            return capacity;
        }
    }
}
```

**Demo.java**

```
package net.coderodde.util;

import java.util.Random;

public class Demo {

    private static final int N = 2000000;

    public static void main(final String... args) {        
        final long seed = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Seed: " + seed);

        System.out.println("-- Random data demo --");

        final Random rnd = new Random(seed);
        Integer[] array1 = getRandomIntegerArray(N, -10000, 10000, rnd);
        Integer[] array2 = array1.clone();

        System.out.print("My natural merge sort:   ");
        long ta1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        net.coderodde.util.Arrays.sort(array2);
        long tb1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println((tb1 - ta1) + " ms.");

        System.out.print("java.util.Arrays.sort(): ");
        long ta2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        java.util.Arrays.sort(array1);
        long tb2 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println((tb2 - ta2) + " ms.");

        System.out.println("Sorted arrays equal: " + 
                Arrays.arraysEqual(array1, array2));

        System.out.println("");

        ////

        System.out.println("-- Presorted data demo --");

        array1 = getPresortedIntegerArray(N);
        array2 = array1.clone();

        System.out.print("My natural merge sort:   ");
        ta1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        net.coderodde.util.Arrays.sort(array2);
        tb1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println((tb1 - ta1) + " ms.");

        System.out.print("java.util.Arrays.sort(): ");
        ta2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        java.util.Arrays.sort(array1);
        tb2 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println((tb2 - ta2) + " ms.");

        System.out.println("Sorted arrays equal: " + 
                Arrays.arraysEqual(array1, array2));
    }

    private static Integer[] getRandomIntegerArray(final int size, 
                                                   final int min,
                                                   final int max,
                                                   final Random rnd) {
        final Integer[] array = new Integer[size];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            array[i] = rnd.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
        }

        return array;
    }

    private static Integer[] getPresortedIntegerArray(final int size) {
        final Integer[] array = new Integer[size];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            array[i] = i % (size / 8);
        }

        for (int i = 0, j = size - 1; i < j; ++i, --j) {
            final Integer tmp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[j];
            array[j] = tmp;
        }

        return array;
    }
}
```

- **RunSizeDeque**

  - Renamed to **UnsafeIntQueue** as to reflect the fact that it is a queue of primitive integers, and that the structure does not check for under-/overflow for efficiency.
  - Hidden from client programmer as a static private inner class of **net.coderodde.util.Arrays**.
  - Avoids using stuff from **java.lang.Math** to compute a capacity that is a power of 2.
  - The user of **UnsafeIntQueue**, i.e. the **sort** method, will do everything needed to avoid under-/overflow.
- **RunCounter**

  - Moved to **net.coderodde.util.Arrays** in the form of a **private** **static** method.
  - I disagree about the need to encapsulate run scanning logic into a subroutine, and that's why:

    1. It's only a loop with a body containing two simple updates.
    2. As it will be called in the worst case O(n) times, and calls in general are expensive, it will introduce an efficiency penalty which I want to avoid.
    3. And, no. The code will not be any more readable.
  - **reverseRun** renamed to **reverse** and made public as it implements an "important algorithm."
- **sort**

  - Eliminates the need for **java.lang.Math**-stuff.
  - What comes to efficiency, just run the demo and you'll see.
  - If the input array has length, say, n = 2k, and is of form
    $$\langle 1, 2, \dots, k, k, k - 1, \dots, 2, 1 \rangle,$$
    natural merge sort will do one pass over the array just to find out that it consists of two runs, the second of which is reversed, reverse it, and do a single merge over the array to merge the two. That's it! 2 and a half passes over the range instead of 
    $$\log 2k = \log k + 1.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a different trick you can use for `getPassAmount` .... the solution I would use is:

```
private static final int getPassCount(int size) {
    return 32 - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(size - 1);
}
```

Note the use of the [`Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#numberOfLeadingZeros-int-). The trick here is to do the boundary-condition logic right, requiring the size-1 and the guard-conditions to check for a size-1 list...

Comment: No. The least value of __size__ ever passed to __getPassCount__ is 1, so that eliminates infinite looping. And on __size__ = 1, zero is exactly what I want it to return as you need no merge passes over the range containing one run.

Comment: @coderodde - updated the answer based on your comment.